# Execute Mail Merge and produce many docs. Type Mismatch error

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, mailmerge

```
            //instantiate wordDoc and wordApp
        string PathDoc, DateTemp = string.Empty;
        DateTime dDateTemp = new DateTime();
        dDateTemp = Convert.ToDateTime(sDate);

        var ds = new DataSet();
        string textDate = dDateTemp.ToString("MM/dd/yy");
        switch (msDateType)
        {
            case "D":
                sSQL = string.Format(msQuery+"'{0}'",textDate);
                break;
            case "W":
                dDateTemp = dDateTemp.AddDays(4);
                DateTemp = dDateTemp.Month.ToString("MM") + "/" + dDateTemp.Day.ToString("dd")
                    + "/" + dDateTemp.Year.ToString("yy");
                sSQL = msQuery + " @textDate";
                //sSQL = msQuery + " '" + textDate + "' AND '" + DateTemp + "'";
                MessageBox.Show(sSQL);
                break;
            case "N":
                sSQL = msQuery;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        string test = "SELECT * FROM ltrFammedNoShow WHERE ApptDt = '06/01/2015'";

        int same = string.Compare(test, sSQL, true);
        using (cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = test;
                // "select top 10 * from ltrFammedNoShow"; // 
                //command.Parameters.Add(@textDate, SqlDbType.NVarChar,15);
                //command.Parameters[@textDate].Value = textDate;
                //MessageBox.Show(command.CommandText);
                var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                adapter.Fill(ds);
            }
        }
        //Set the path and document of the letter to be used for the merge 
        PathDoc = msPath + "\"" + msDocument;

        //Create a new instance of the word Application
        wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        //Add a new document
        wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        wordDoc.Select();

        //Create MailMerge data document
        CreateDataDoc(ref wordApp, ref ds);         
        wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(Template: @"D:\ClinicLetters\Fammed\NoShow.doc");
        wordApp.Visible = true;
        wordDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(@"D:\\data.doc");

        //wordDoc.MailMerge.Destination = WdMailMergeDestination.wdSendToNewDocument;
        //wordDoc.MailMerge.Execute(ref oFalse);

        wordDoc.MailMerge.Execute(ds);
        //wordDoc.Words.Last.InsertBreak(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak);

        //Close the original form document
        wordDoc.Saved = false;
        wordDoc.Close(ref oFalse, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

        //Release reference
        wordDoc = null;
        wordApp = null;
```

I tried everything I could think of to product multiple letters ( that stay in the same doc for easier printing purpose) but I kepting getting a Type Mismatch error. Can someone help? All opinions are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: To do a mail merge, An alternative solution to Microsoft.Office.Interop is to create a real word document doing standard mail merged and linked to a csv file. In c#, you would create the csv file with all variable fields (one line for each letter) and run Word (using Process.start)  to display or print the letters.

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264  wordDoc.MailMerge.Execute(ds);

Answer (score 1):

The specific error you describe occurs because the parameter for .Execute is not the DataSet that you want to use (ds) but a boolean that specifies what Word does when an error occurs in the merge.

Difficult to see beyond that as it depends partly on exactly what your CreateDataDoc method does.